# Why is my PHP not detecting my submit button press and thus not executing my function?

Tags: php

I have the following HTML like halfway down my index.php page:

```
<form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Reset Game" class="reset-button" title="Admitting defeat?"></form>
```

At the top of my page, I have the following check:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) {
    if ($_POST["submit"] === "Reset Game"] {
        $_SESSION["word"] = generate_word("dictionary.txt");
        $_SESSION["word-progress"] = turn_to_underscores($_SESSION["word"]);
    }
}
```

Which generates the word for my hangman game, as well as the underscored version. Here are those functions:

```
    /**
     * Generate a random word from the given dictionary file
     * @param $filename Name of the dictionary file
     * @return Random word
     */
    function generate_word($filename) {
        $dictionary_file = new SplFileObject($filename);
        $dictionary_file->seek(rand(0, 80367));

        return trim($dictionary_file->current());
    }

    /**
     * Accepts a word and returns it as underscores for obfuscation
     * @param $word A given word
     * @return Returns the word as underscores
     */
    function turn_to_underscores($word) {
        $underscored_word = "";

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
            $underscored_word .= "_";
        }

        return $underscored_word;
    }
```

Which I bring in with a `require "functions.php";` call.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST')` instead. it's 100% reliable, unlike (as your case demonstrates) checking for particular form fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your submit button has no name attribute, so it won't be a successful control and won't appear in the submitted data (certainly not as `$_POST["submit"]`).

Answer (score 1):

Give a `name="submit"` to the `submit` form input.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php_error.log file.  It should say something about how you're trying to access an undefined index "submit".

The problem is that there is no submit key because you haven't given the submit input a "name" value.